# Transform frame of particles sim into object

Tags: mesh, particles, keyframes

I want to make this exact frame of the simulation an mesh object so I can append into another file, how do I do that? I searched and didnt find an answer.Its a plane using explode modifier with particles simulations.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "apply" the explode modifier when positioned at the frame you want.

[image]